# How to add my database file (.MDF) in app folder using InstallShield Limited in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installshield

I am using InstallShield limited edition in Visual Studio 2013, and I'm having problems of write permission on database. I want to add database file in the app folder - how to do that using InstallShield?

And how to modify connection string for app folder on Windows?

Comment: INSTALLDIR is default to program files thus read only. you should put writable data under one of the AppDataFolder folders.

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 how to modify connection string for app data folder

Comment: string.format with environment.getfolderpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="+Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)+"\\Drives.mdf;Integrated Security=True; Connect Timeout=60; ");
```